# Changing order of stacked areas

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to order the stacked `geom_area` in an arbitrary way.

For instance:

```
investments <- data.frame(Date = c(as.Date('2019-01-01'), as.Date('2019-01-01'),
                                   as.Date('2019-01-01'), as.Date('2019-01-02'),
                                   as.Date('2019-01-02'), as.Date('2019-01-02')),
                          Amount = c(100, 200, 150, 120, 200, 130),
                          InvestType = c("Shares", "Cash", "Bonds", 
                                         "Shares", "Cash", "Bonds"))

ggplot()+
  geom_area(data = investments,
            aes(x = Date, y = Amount, fill = InvestType))
```

[image: Investments]

This gives the above graph with the stacked areas ordered "Shares, Cash, Bonds".
Now I want "Cash" to always be on top.

I tried sorting the dataframe with:

```
investments  <- arrange(investments, 
                        factor(InvestType, levels = c("Shares", "Bonds", "Cash")))
```

This sorted the data frame by InvestType but did not change the order of the stacked areas.

Comment: `InvestType` needs to be a factor (with levels in the correct order) in the dataframe you pass to `ggplot()`. Try running something like `investments$InvestType <- factor(investments$InvestType, levels = c("Shares", "Bonds", "Cash"))` before plotting?

Comment: Yes @Z.Lin that does what I want. I was confusing sorting the data with having the factor levels in the right order. Thx

Answer (score 0):

@Z.Lin gave the correct answer in the comments.
I needed the stacked area variable to be a factor and have the levels set in the right order.
Converted using
`investments$InvestType <- factor(investments$InvestType, levels = c("Shares", "Bonds", "Cash"))` before plotting as per the comment.